# Foreign keys in web2py database

Tags: python, foreign-keys, web2py

I use web2py framework with two tables. How can I refer one field from first table into second table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the section on table relationships and JOINs from the [web2py chapter on databases](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06#One-to-many-relation)

> To illustrate how to implement one to many relations with the web2py DAL, define another table "dog" that refers to the table "person" which we redefine here:

```
>>> db.define_table('person',
                    Field('name'),
                    format='%(name)s')
>>> db.define_table('dog',
                    Field('name'),
                    Field('owner', db.person),
                    format='%(name)s')
```

You'll need to provide more information if you are looking for something that's not covered in that reference.

Answer (score 1):

See [The Database Abstraction Layer](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06) chapter of the book, in particular, the section on [One to Many Relations](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06#One-to-Many-Relation). If you're working with a pre-existing/legacy database, see [Legacy Databases and Keyed Tables](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06#Legacy-Databases-and-Keyed-Tables). Also, here's an [example](http://web2py.com/examples/default/examples#database_examples).